# How can clear Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational event log with powershell command?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, event-log

I wanna clear `Operational` type logs in the following path in `Event Viewer` :

<kbd>Applications and Services Logs</kbd> / <kbd>Microsoft</kbd> / <kbd>Windows</kbd> / <kbd>DriverFrameworks-UserMode</kbd>

I tried with this command in **power-shell** and run that with *Administrator* :

> ```
> remove-eventlog -logname $"Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational"
> ```

But it doesn't work and i get this error :

[image]

Actually, I want to track-down (connected \ disconnected) usb devices logs and clear them.

Regards ....

Answer (score 3):

Firstly this...

```
$"Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational"
```

... is the wrong syntax. What you are doing here is not a use case for it. [The '$' (as well as many others)](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens) has a special meaning in PowerShell and you do not use single/double quotes with plain simple strings with it.

The error message means the log is truly not there or you are not passing in the complete path to the log.

The remove verb does not mean clear or empty, It means to delete/destroy the file. This a System file, so that is not a thing.

> Remove-EventLog
>
> ***Deletes an event log or unregisters an event source.***
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1

Be sure to read up on a cmdlet before you use it. Don't guess or you can really destroy your system(s), enterprise(s).

['PowerShell clear windows event logs'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20clear%20windows%20event%20logs&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershelclear%20windows%20event%20logs&sc=1-33&sk=&cvid=500E3E23A6B04CE78E7DB1A3671D51D5)

Always, always use -WhatIf and -Confirm:$true on all destructive code (delete, rename, move, et al) to be sure you will get what you'd expect before removing/commenting out those switches from your code.

Always to a Get-* before a destructive action.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'YourLogNameOrFullpathHere'
```

Open EventViewer (which you show you've done - but you are looking at one log ...
but you are saying you want to clear another) to get the full name to the log, or do this...

```
# List all logs
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -EA silentlycontinue
```

... or list a log target

```
 Get-WinEvent -ListLog 'Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational'

# Results
<#
LogMode   MaximumSizeInBytes RecordCount LogName                                                                                                                                               
-------   ------------------ ----------- -------                                                                                                                                               
Circular             1052672             Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational  
#>


Get-WinEvent -ListLog 'Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational'
# Results
<#
LogMode   MaximumSizeInBytes RecordCount LogName                                                                                                                                               
-------   ------------------ ----------- -------                                                                                                                                               
Circular             1052672        1901 Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational 
#>
```

then use...

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'YourLogNameOrFullpathHere'

# Example
Get-WinEvent -ListLog 'Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational' | Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogConfiguration

Name                           MemberType   Definition                                                              
----                           ----------   ----------                                                              
...                                                       
FileSize                       NoteProperty long FileSize=1052672                                                   
IsLogFull                      NoteProperty bool IsLogFull=False                                                    
LastAccessTime                 NoteProperty datetime LastAccessTime=28-Jul-20 01:15:05                              
LastWriteTime                  NoteProperty datetime LastWriteTime=28-Jul-20 01:15:05                               
...
RecordCount                    NoteProperty long RecordCount=1903                                                   
...
LogFilePath                    Property     string LogFilePath {get;set;}                                           
...
LogMode                        Property     System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogMode LogMode {get;set;}      
LogName                        Property     string LogName {get;}                                                   
LogType                        Property     System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogType LogType {get;}          
...
#>

(Get-WinEvent -ListLog 'Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational').LogFilePath

Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational' | 
Select-Object -First 3 | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS

TimeCreated         Id LevelDisplayName Message                                                                                                                                                
-----------         -- ---------------- -------                                                                                                                                                
28-Jul-20 01:24:34 105 Information      Diagnostic module {45de1ea9-10bc-4f96-9b21-4b6b83dbf476} (%windir%\system32\radardt.dll) started troubleshooting scenario {180b3a99-8c39-4f12-b631-2...
28-Jul-20 01:24:34 100 Information      Diagnostic module {45de1ea9-10bc-4f96-9b21-4b6b83dbf476} (%windir%\system32\radardt.dll) detected a problem for scenario {180b3a99-8c39-4f12-b631-20...
28-Jul-20 01:19:34 105 Information      Diagnostic module {45de1ea9-10bc-4f96-9b21-4b6b83dbf476} (%windir%\system32\radardt.dll) started troubleshooting scenario {180b3a99-8c39-4f12-b631-2...
#>
```

FYI - Get-WinEvent is the replacement for the depreciated Get-EventLog. Yet, either can be used, for now.

The physical location of the log is here:

```
(Get-ChildItem -pa 'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs' -Filter '*Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS*').FullName
# Results
<#
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS%4Operational.evtx
#>
```

The cmdlet you want is...

> Clear-EventLog (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-eventlog

```
Clear-EventLog -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS/Operational' -WhatIf -Confirm:$true
```

Comment: Thanks man, i solved my problem with `wevtutil cl Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational` command. anyway i upvote your answer...

Comment: No worries. Workarounds are always a thing for us all when we end up losing more hair staring at some catch22.